# http headers being already sent - elmah logging the error (MVC3 app)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, http-headers

When I log into the staging environment on our site I see elmah log this error:-

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been sent.

In the mvc 3 code we have an ActionResult which processes the user log-on. The code contains the following:

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies["returnUrl"];
if (cookie != null && IsSafe(cookie.Value))
{
    // Set expire the cookie and set the return url
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.MinValue;
    Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    return this.Redirect(cookie.Value);
}
return RedirectToAction(MVC.Home.Index());
```

So the error looks to be the line: `return this.Redirect(cookie.Value);`

We are trying to redirect after the headers have been modified? Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.